# Laravel import model in function

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to import the model in function and call create function of the specific model.
I know which model to call from `Route::currentRoute();`, so it must look like

```
$model = Route::currentRouteName() // return like 'Blog/Post'

$create = new App\Models\$model::create($request->input());
```

Any ideas on how to do it in that way?

Answer (score 2):

You must put the full model path into the string, then it will work.
Also make sure that you replace forward slashes with backslashes.
And if you use 'create' you don't need 'new'.

Here the final result:

```
$model = str('Blog/Post')->replace('/', '\\');
$fullPath = 'App\Models\\' . $model;
$create = $fullPath::create($request->input()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just use call it putting a full path of the model. for eg:

```
public function callModel(Request $request){
  $create = App\Models\$model::create($request->input());
  dd($create);
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).